# KNIME - Java snippet - DoubleCell/Java type double []

Tags: java, double, listcellrenderer, knime

I have a problem with node containing this column type:

```
ListCell (Collection of: ListCell (Collection of: DoubleCell))
```

Data looks like this:

> [[-0.518, -1.431], [-1.431, -0.518]]

Next node is `Java Snippet`. In input options, the only `Java type` option for this column is `String`, which is wrong as you can see:

> ERROR     Java Snippet  Execute failed: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to  [Ljava.lang.Object;

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think that is a bug in the Java Snippet node.

Comment: That is what I think too. I posted this to KNIME forum, but nobody has answered yet: http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-users/java-snippet-doublecelljava-type-double-problem Maybe it will be better to post it as bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got reply on KNIME forum (http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-users/java-snippet-doublecelljava-type-double-problem)

> Hi jirinovo,
>
> the JavaSnippet node can handle collections of doubles, etc. but not
>   collections of collections.
>
> We will change the type definitions in the JavaSnippet node in order
>   to handle this more dynamically and be more flexible. However this
>   will take some time, probably until summer 2015 latest.
>
> Cheers, Kilian

Answer (score 0):

The JavaSnippet node can handle collections of doubles, etc. but not collections of collections.